# Is it possible to alter the size of all html headings with a single css statement while still maintaining their relative sizes to each other?

Tags: html, css

I know that I can change the size of individual html headings using css (e.g., `h1 {font-size: 0.5em;}`).  However I would like to overall reduce the size of all the headings (h1, h2, h3, etc...) while retaining their relative sizes to each other (h1 > h2 > h3, etc...).

Is it possible change all the heading sizes with a single css statement or will I have to specify each heading separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set e.g. the font size of `h1` and `h2` in the same CSS statement, except to the same declared value.

However, if you wish to make it possible to change the font sizes of headings in a centralized manner, you can wrap all headings in `div` elements, e.g.

```
<div class=heading><h1>...</h1></div>
<div class=heading><h2>...</h2></div>
```

Now, assuming you have set font sizes in `em` units (or percentages), e.g. `h1 { font-size: 2em } h2 { font-size: 1.5em }`, you can modify them all by setting font size on the enclosing `div` element, e.g.

```
.heading { font-size: 0.9em; }
```

This would reduce the font size of all headings by 10%, without affecting font sizes on the page otherwise.

P.S. It is odd to set the font size of the main heading to one half of the font size of its parent. It is difficult to see what you are trying to accomplish. It is normally sufficient to set font sizes in `em` units using some reasonable scale.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this makes sense.  Just to answer the question in your P.S., I am a professor and I write all the materials for my classes in html to make them easy to distribute.  However sometimes I need to print them out for the students and the h1 headings seem really large in these cases.  I can hack it by using a "lower" heading where I would normally use h1 but I kinda like to keep things semantic by using h1 for the main heading etc...  So I was looking for a simple css solution to keep things flexible.

Comment: You can use a separate print style sheet, or you can add rules that apply to print media only into your style sheet, e.g. `h1 { font-size: 1.2em }`. This will make the font size of 1st level heading 1.2 times the copy font size. The `em` unit in `font-size` always relates to the font size of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be accomplished in CSS, but try SASS (http://sass-lang.com/) if you want to keep your code short.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font-size on a parent element like the body. If you are using ems or rems then they will scale up or down.

```
body {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ferne97/FXKvx/

I added a button that toggles a class of `small` to the body tag which will set the font-size to 80% when added.

Comment: Such changing is implied in the question: the very point of using `em` is that the font size changes when the parent’s font size is changed.